# メタ版の問い合わせページに翻訳できない文字列がある

Tags: バグ, 対応予定, 翻訳, メタ

### 不具合事象

[メタ版の問い合わせページ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)の英文が ja.traducir.win 上に登録されていないようです。以下はメタ版の問い合わせページのスクリーンショットです。

この画像を見ると、いくつか未翻訳の文字列があることがわかります。たとえば、このうち「If you have a question...」と「You might find these links...」という2つの文字列を ja.traducir.win で調べてみます：

- 「If you have a question」の ja.traducir.win での[検索結果](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=If%20you%20have%20a%20question)
- 「You might find these links」の ja.traducir.win での[検索結果](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=You%20might%20find%20these%20links%20)

これらの検索結果を確認するとわかるように、これらの英文は ja.traducir.win の検索結果に表示されません。一通り試しましたが、少なくともスクリーンショットに写っている英文は翻訳できない状態のようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 再現環境

- OS：Windows 10 64-bit
- ブラウザ：Opera One(バージョン: 104.0.4944.36)

Comment: Stack Exchange社様には、私が回答で述べた認識で間違い無いか確認していただきたく、エスカレーションいたします。
間違い無ければ、ユーザー側で日本語版の文案を出し、それを設定していただく、という流れにしたいです。

Comment: @mjy 様、確認が大変遅くなって申し訳ありませんが、おおよそのところはおっしゃる通りだと思います。日本語版の文案を出し、それを設定する流れにできれば。文案が固まりましたらコミュニティチームから依頼をかけてゆきたいです。

Comment: @JNat  対応タグに変更してくださりありがとうございます。ユーザー側で出された日本語版の文案が固まり次第、すぐにご連絡致します。

Answer (score 4):

この部分はサイト毎にカスタマイズできる部分のようです。例えば[Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/contact)だとUbuntu関連の連絡先のみになっており、[ロシア語版](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)だと空になっています。

（追記: 日本語版も[本サイト側](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)は空なんですね。開始当初、空にしておくことになったものを、メタサイト側での作業が忘れられたのかも知れません。）

ですので、この部分を日本語化するなら、通常の翻訳フローに乗せてもらうのでは無く、日本語版独自の文章（日本語話者向けのリンク先にするなど）を提案し、差し替えてもらう形になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

[翻訳案はこちらに](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4014/3054)、ということですので、私の案です。

#### この欄は空にすることを提案します

[当初の回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3969/3054)に追記した通り、この欄は[本サイト側](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)では空になっています。それに合わせ、メタサイト側も空にすることを提案します。ロシア語版と同じ対応です。

理由は、やや消極的なものとなりますが、以下です。

- 特に書くべき事が思い付かない
- おそらく当初の予定でも、こうする筈だったであろう事である
- できるだけ、通常の翻訳フローに従わない部分を増やしたくない

Answer (score 0):

翻訳案はこちらにお願いいたします‍♀️。

---

ヘルプセンター > 問い合わせ先

If you have a question about a Stack Exchange site, the best place to ask is on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) or the site's own meta - which is in the top bar under the Help icon ❓.

You might find these links useful:

[Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/)
[Yahoo! Help Central](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account)
[Google Contact](https://about.google/contact-google/)
[Ubuntu Contact](https://ubuntu.com/contact-us)

アカウントの削除やマージが必要な場合、またはメタで対処できない問題がある場合は、以下の「サポートに問い合わせる」オプションを使用してください。

---

Comment: これは、日本語版独自の内容にして良いのでしょうか。
それとも、原文を翻訳するのみにするべきでしょうか。

Comment: 日本語版独自の内容がよろしいかと思います‍♀️